* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Error: URL.protocol is not implemented, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

Here is my code. Why am I getting this error?
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('matrex', () => App);

